# Mysql - Pass subsequent read query after write to master Server

Tags: mysql

Have Mysql-5.6 single Master and 3 slaves configured. Have Write queries directed to master and read to slave. After write to master, immediate read query is directed to slave, which results the old data. I need to pass the immediate read query after write to the master server. Is there any tools / way to achieve it.

Comment: What is your setup? What are you using to direct read/writes to different servers? You haven't really provided anything that we can use to help.

Comment: In application, master ip address mentioned to pass write queries. And 3 slaves are in Hardware LB, In application, LB ip address is mentioned to pass read queries.

Comment: You need to make modifications to your application to allow reads to master when requested. This isn't a mysql issue.

Comment: I want to allow only subsequent reads after write to master. Checking if any tools available to achieve it.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but your application needs to know where to route the query. You will need to write some logic to allow the application to read from the master server if you want to read data that you have just written. Again, this is nothing to do with mysql - but an issue with the routing of queries within your application.

Comment: We have a similar setup (1 master 3 slaves). The only "fix" for this issue we have is to consider each query (when writing it) and decide if can run on a slave or not.